# Accessing Header Text property of GridView TemplateField in the Code Behind when it is set from Header Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in an asp .net application, where the Header Text of a template field is set in the Header Template of the field, as a label (where it will come from the resource file). Below is the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" meta:resourcekey="grdViewResource">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource1">
           <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblNameHeader" Text="Name" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblNameHeaderResource1"/>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblNameValue" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In code behind I am trying to access the HeaderText set on the column like this

```
var headerText = gridView.Columns[0].HeaderText;
```

But the value is coming Empty and I am not able to retrieve it from the gridView.Columns' HeaderTemplate property as well.

Please help me.

Comment: The HeaderText property is for use with the HeaderText property of your ItemTemplate. Not with a HeaderTemplate.

Comment: @mason: sorry. i could not quite get it :( you meant to say, the way I have done the markup is wrong?

Comment: @Niranjan - If you set the HeaderText property of the TemplateField instead of using a HeaderTemplate, then you could retrieve the text in code behind with that same HeaderText property.

Comment: @ConnorsFan But the HeaderText has to come from app local resource file. I tried adding meta:resourcekey property on TemplateField, it did not work.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It was a goof-up, I am able to set the HeaderText directly using meta:resourcekey, my resource file was not inside the proper directory. In my original application, now i need to change, my 40-45 columns from HeaderTemplate :( Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

You are missing a closing `</asp:TemplateField>`. Your `asp:Label` is missing a `runat="server"` attribute.

If you want to use the .HeaderText property, this should be your markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" meta:resourcekey="grdViewResource">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource1" HeaderText="Name">
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblNameValue" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

If you want to use a HeaderTemplate with custom markup in it, then you need to cast the column to a TemplateField, then access the controls within it.

Comment: Apologies for the code :) i typed it manually into the question. I took up this approach, since, the production code has the HeaderTemplate, now i might have to change all the columns this way. Thanks a lot!